# safe numeric type converter

Tags: c++, converting, c++20, casting

I have written a function for casting between built in numeric types. I built it to check if the source value is within the range of the destination value, and to provide a nicely legible error if not. I also built it such that float -> conversions round instead of truncate and so that int -> float conversions do not error if the int value is not exactly representable as an int (so do best effort). It can be assumed that there will be no nan or inf in the input (if the input is float). [Example code is here](https://godbolt.org/z/zoPaYzx3T). My questions:

1. is this safe or are there cases that i am not checking?
2. are there some easy opportunities for optimization (for execution speed in non-error cases)?

main function:

```
// function to convert between types, inputs and outputs can be
// integral (including bool) and floating point
// throws if conversion not possible (including due to overflow)
// NB: we don't care if an integral to be converted to float cannot
// be precisely represented, so int types->float types conversion
// always succeeds
template <typename T, typename S>
    requires (std::is_integral_v<S> || std::is_floating_point_v<S>) && (std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
constexpr
T convertType(S val_)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S, T>)
        // source and target are the same type, no conversion needed
        return val_;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S, bool>)
    {
        // bool can be directly cast to any of the possible output types
        return static_cast<T>(val_);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
        // any input can be directly converted to bool through the not operator
        return !!val_;
    else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<S> && std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        if (std::in_range<T>(val_))
            return static_cast<T>(val_);
        else
            throw std::range_error(std::format("Cannot convert value: the value contained in the input type '{}' ({}) is outside the range of the requested output type '{}'", typeToString<S>(), val_, typeToString<T>()));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<S> && std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
    {
        // float -> float, may overflow if target type is smaller than source type
        if (sizeof(T) < sizeof(S) && (val_ > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() || val_ < std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()))
            throw std::range_error(std::format("Cannot convert value: the value contained in the input type '{}' ({}) is outside the range of the requested output type '{}'", typeToString<S>(), val_, typeToString<T>()));

        return static_cast<T>(val_);
    }
    // now either float -> int, or int -> float
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<S>)
    {
        // float -> int. We round the float away from zero
        if (val_ + .5 > std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), 0))
            throw std::overflow_error(std::format("Cannot convert value: the value contained in the input type '{}' ({}) is too large for the requested output type '{}'", typeToString<S>(), val_, typeToString<T>()));
        else if (val_ - .5 < std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), 0))
            throw std::underflow_error(std::format("Cannot convert value: the value contained in the input type '{}' ({}) is too small for the requested output type '{}'", typeToString<S>(), val_, typeToString<T>()));
        else
        {
            // in range, now cast, rounding as appropriate
            if (std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t> && (val_ + .5 > nextafter(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max(), 0)))
                // can't use lround/llround, use a poor man's version that rounds away from zero
                return static_cast<T>(val_ + .5 * ((val_ > 0.) ? 1. : ((val_ < 0.) ? -1. : 0.))); //+.5 if positive, -.5 if negative, +0 if 0 for good measure
            else if (sizeof(T) > sizeof(long))
                return static_cast<T>(llround(val_));
            else
                return static_cast<T>(lround(val_));
        }
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
    {
        // int -> float
        // NB: we ignore whether the value is representable by the float, so nothing to check here
        return static_cast<T>(val_);
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert(always_false<T>, "Conversion not implemented");
        return -1;  // shut up static analysis
    }
}
```

required includes, helpers and testing code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <format>

// helper needed to be able to do static_assert(false,...), e.g. to mark some constexpr if branches as todo
template <class...> constexpr std::false_type always_false{};
// another helper
template <typename T>
std::string typeToString()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
        return "boolean";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>)
        return "uint8";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, uint16_t>)
        return "uint16";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, uint32_t>)
        return "uint32";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>)
        return "uint64";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int8_t>)
        return "int8";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int16_t>)
        return "int16";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int32_t>)
        return "int32";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int64_t>)
        return "int64";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        return "float";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        return "double";
}

int main()
{
    auto f = convertType<float>(3.);
    auto f2 = convertType<float>(false);

    auto i = convertType<unsigned int>(-1);
    auto i2 = convertType<unsigned int>(-1.);
    auto i3 = convertType<unsigned int>(1);
    auto i4 = convertType<unsigned int>(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
    auto i5 = convertType<int64_t>(1LL);

    auto b = convertType<bool>(4ULL);
    auto d = convertType<double>(4ULL);
}
```

Comment: An automated test, such as a unit test, is "self evaluating", it "knows the right answer" and will report on incorrect answers. In contrast the test here, `main()`, at best verifies "no crash" and successful compilation. A subset of your target conversion pairs are round-tripable, and that would be worth verifying. Recommend you implement some automated tests that would notice if e.g. an Evil Maintenance Engineer incremented or doubled the quantity being converted. You'd be surprised at what's in  code that maintenance bug fixes sometimes offer for merging down to `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It is unclear what it does

I am sure there is a use case where this function does exactly what you want. However, without looking very closely at the source code of this function it is very hard to tell what conversions are being done.

First, the name `convertType<>()` is very generic. How does it convert? `static_cast<>()` also converts types. But clearly your functions does something different, but it doesn't tell me what.

Second, it's a very mixed bag. Sometimes it is exact, sometimes it rounds. Conversion of anything to `bool` is allowed for some reason. `inf` and `nan` are not handled explicitly. Interestingly, you can convert a `nan` from one float type to another, but trying to convert an `inf` results in an exception being thrown, even though the latter seems like it should be fine.

I would define exactly what this does and make sure the name reflects it. Maybe you even want multiple functions. For example, an `exactConvert<>()` to allow conversions that preserve the exact mathematical value, or a `roundtripConvert<>()` that allows values to round trip such that you get the original value back, `rangeCheckConvert()` that just checks that the value is in range of the new type but allows imprecise conversions, and so on.

I would strongly recommend forbidding conversions to and from `bool`, or alternatively treat it like a 1-bit *integer*, and for example don't allow 3.1415 to be converted to `bool`.

## Correctness

Using `sizeof(T) > sizeof(long)` to decide whether to use `llround()` or `lround()` looks very fishy; tt's perfectly legal to have an architecture where `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long)`. Although I can't imagine `lround()` and `llround()` doing something different then.

The exact [fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) like `std::uint64_t` are *optional* parts of the standard, so they are not guaranteed to be defined.

C++23 introduced [`std::float16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/floating-point). When using this type, a 32-bits or larger integer is not always in range of that.

## Write a proper test suite

As `J_H` mentioned in the comments, your `main()` is not a substitute for a proper test suite. Also, you want to meticulously check all the corner cases, like denormals, values right at the edge of the source and destination type's ranges, and also check that exceptions are thrown in cases where they should.